# apache(cpanel) + mod_wsgi + Python3 + Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, cpanel, wsgi

Goodnight everyone. I'm trying to do the deployment of an application developed with django in a VPS. This VPS has installed centos 6.8. Apache is configured through the cpanel. After installing python3 and wsgi proceeded to configure the icnlude of the virtual host, which was as follows:

```
<ifmodule mod_wsgi.c>

    WSGIDaemonProcess pruebas.caso.org python-path=/home/admin/pruebas.org/envSpf/spf:/home/admin/pruebas.org/envSpf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
    WSGIProcessGroup pruebas.caso.org
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/pruebas.org/envSpf/spf/spf/wsgi.py

</ifmodule>

Alias /static "/home/admin/pruebas.or/envSpf/spf/static/"
<Directory /home/admin/pruebas.or/envSpf/spf/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media "/home/admin/pruebas.or/envSpf/spf/media/"
<Directory /home/admin/pruebas.or/envSpf/spf/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/admin/pruebas.or/envSpf/spf/spf>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

With this configuration at the moment the server gives me the following response in the browser request:

> **Service Temporarily Unavailable** The server is temporarily unable to
>   service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
>   Please try again later. Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily
>   Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument
>   to handle the request.

The VPS provider is not very helpful and the error log refers to another domain (?? !!!). I would appreciate any guidance that could help me resolve this inconvenience.

Comment: You would have to see the error logs from the Apache. If you have it, show what the error from logs is, not the browser error. If the service provider is not helpful, then go find a different service provider.

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you for responding, I finally managed to solve the deployment problem. If you look at the path of the static files I had made an unintentional error in transcribing. I wrote .or and it should have been .org. Anyway, although I can already see the site and navigate perfectly well in the frontend, the .css and .js of the admin are not loaded and I have the totally flat admin. By the way ... no errors in the log. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you run ``python manage.py collectstatic`` on the target system to collect all the static assets. Make sure ``STATIC_ROOT`` in Django settings module matches what ``Alias`` directive for ``/static`` is set to in Apache configuration.

Comment: Hello brother, I solved, I had a problem in configuring the alias in the virtual host. So far, everything goes smoothly. I still find it hard to understand the issue of statics in production. Can you refer me any documentation? Thanks again

Comment: The Django documentation explains it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files